# Python: How do I check if the last three number of a variable to be 000 or not?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Incorporating with excel, I'm looking for a solution that would check if a company code ends with a 000 or not (anything else) by implementing if statements. The output should be a True or false statement. I do not know how exactly to start. I thought of using switches, but I do not exactly know how to implement a function or action after switches.

For Instance:
[Excel Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHbXr.png)

Example:
If code ends with 000: true
If code ends with 001: false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) for test some column, here `column`:

```
#if necessary convert file to DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(file)

df['test'] = df['column'].str.endswith('000')
```

Comment: is df a function under Pandas?

Comment: @Joe - no, `df` is `pandas DataFrame`

Comment: How exactly do I implement it into a for loop with if statement so that I can write the true or false into a different column?

Comment: @Joe - I think it is big mistake working with `for` in pandas, because it is not designed for it, maybe check some tutorials [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html). In pandas working with masks, like here `df['column'].str.endswith('000')` is mask filled by `True/False`

Comment: @Joe - But if want working with `xlsxwriter.Workbook` is is more complicated and I never working with it, I guss some loops there are necessary.

Comment: in pandas is obviously first step create DataFrame, processing data and last write to file.

Comment: @Joe - `s = df['Corporate Code']` and then `s.to_excel(writer,'Sheet',index=False)` I think you need if want avoid first column, else `s.to_excel(writer,'Sheet')`